# Scatterplot Confusion

Tags: statistics

I have just entered data into a scatterplot (by hand and by calc.), and for some reason the correlation is negative. This is weird due to the context of the problem: the x-axis is how long a swimmer has been swimming in minutes, and the y axis is his heart rate. Why is his heart rate decreasing as he exercises MORE? So, the question is -- in the context of this problem -- why is the correlation negative?

r= -0.7460

Help?

Comment: i would REALLY appreciate some help :3

Comment: Can you provide more information? It will be hard to give you any type of useful help with the information you've provided.

Comment: why is the swimmers heart rate decreasing the more he exercises?

Comment: thats what the question is asking. Is the association + or -, obviously - if you plot it, and explain why in conext of the problem which is the swim time on the x axis and heart rate on the y

Comment: Is this just some data that was given in a math a problem, or is it real data, that came from real measurements of a real swimmer. If the former, there is no reason to believe that the answer will be realistic -- people who make up math problems don't necessarily know anything about exercise physiology. If the latter, then this question is about biology, not about mathematics, so this is the wrong place to ask it.

Comment: Some possible explanations: (1) heartrate jumps up when the swimmer first experiences the shock of diving into cold water, or (2) the swimmer swims too fast at first, and then adjusts his pace later, after realizing his mistake, or (3) the excitement and adrelain surge gradually abates as the swim goes on. I would expect heartrate to be fairly constant in the later stages of the race, so you still won't get positive correlation with time.

Comment: WOW @bubba, I couldnt even think of ONE reason and you came up with 3, thanks. I have a hard time applying problems to real life scenerios. Thanks again.!!!!

Comment: After a little more thought ... correlation does not need to have a reason. Correlation and causality are two different things. Maybe the swimmers whose heartrate went down (for whatever reason) were somehow able to swim faster as a result, or maybe there's no causal relationship at all. It's quite possible that this is the point of the question -- to teach you that correlation does not imply cause.

Comment: DO you happen to have the regression model used to produce the scatter plot? Perhaps it is actually showing the average heart rate increase? Perhaps it shows the rate at which the swimmer's heart rate changes? Make sure you aren't overlooking a small piece of nuance in the sentence. Other than that, since it is a stats class, look for an actual analytical answer. i.e. - "the swimmer's heart rate decreases because the coefficient of t is negative. Thus, as t increase the value of the regression decreases."  Something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Is this just some data that was given in a math a problem, or is it real data, that came from real measurements of a real swimmer?

If the former, there is no reason to believe that the answer will be realistic -- people who make up math problems don't necessarily know anything about exercise physiology. If the latter, then this question is about biology, not about mathematics, so this is the wrong place to ask it.

But, I know a little about exercise physiology, so here are a few ideas:

(1) heartrate jumps up when the swimmer first experiences the shock of diving into cold water, or

(2) the swimmer swims too fast at first, and then adjusts his pace later, after realizing his mistake, or

(3) the excitement and adrelain surge gradually abates as the swim goes on.

Actually, I would expect heartrate to be fairly constant in the later stages of the race, so you still won't get positive correlation with time.

Another consideration is that correlation does not need to have a reason. Correlation and causality are two different things. Maybe the swimmers whose heartrate went down (for whatever reason) were somehow able to swim faster as a result, or maybe there's no causal relationship at all. It's quite possible that this is the point of the question -- to teach you that correlation does not imply cause.